# Set the height of an item inside a JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a `JCombobox` with many items and first of all them is a `NULL` value

When opening the combobox, all the items have a normal height but not the first one which is a really thin strip at the top of all. That makes really difficult to be clickable since it looks like there is nothing (but it is there and you can select it).

The question is, how can I make this item to have the same height than the other items?

More information:

- I have tried with `JCombobox.setPrototypeDisplayValue()` with a normal String like "XXXXX" or with one of the normal items, but that changes the width but not the height.
- The null value is represented in the `JCombobox` with an empty String ("") via a `ObjectToStringConverter` subclass:

`org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate
          (combobox, ConfigurableToStringConverter.INSTANCE);`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the default renderer used for comboboxes (see `DefaultListCellRenderer` class). Check the getListCellRendererComponent() method. Call super.getListCellRendererComponent() and if value is NULL set empty string (or space char string " ") as the value.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that works... I mean, if I change my ObjectToStringConverter to return "-" or white space " " instead of the empty string, the item gets normal height. However the problem arises with the Autocomplete which returns a "beep" warning when it tries to fullfill the first element with that character (white space) and finds no element matching

Comment: I'm not sure how renderer could change this. I don't think autocompletion uses renderer. I would rather check editor's code.

Comment: I already had overriden the DefaultListCellRenderer but now I make what you suggest. Thanks

And forget my previous comment

Answer (score 2):

Looking at camickr's [Combo Box Popup](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/), the code source shows `setPreferredSize` for `Width`, but I can't see any reason not to use `setPreferredSize` for `Height` the same way.

There is only question is if there may be some conflict between `SwingX#AutoCompleteDecorator` and standard Swing code